# How to find spark master URL on Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am new to spark and trying to install spark on Amazon cluster with version 1.3.1. when i do

```
SparkConf sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSQLTest").setMaster("local[2]");
```

it does work for me , however i came to know that this is for testing purpose i can set local[2]

When  i tried to use cluster mode i changed it to

```
SparkConf sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSQLTest").setMaster("spark://localhost:7077");
```

with this i am getting below error

Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused
15/06/10 15:22:21 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost:7077/user/Master..

Could someone please let me how to set the master url.

Comment: I recommend not using EMR. Follow the official documentation instead: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the bootstrap action from https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark the configuration is setup for Spark on YARN.  So just set master to `yarn-client` or `yarn-cluster`.  Be sure to define the number of executors with memory and cores. More details about Spark on YARN at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

**Addition regarding executor settings for memory and core sizing:**

Take a look at the default YARN node manager configs for each type at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html, specifically `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`.   You can determine the number of cores from the basic EC2 info url (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). The max size of the executor memory has to fit within the max allocation less Spark's overhead and in increments of 256MB. A good description of this calculation is at http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/. Don't forget that a little over half the executor memory can be used for RDD cache.

Comment: out of curiosity wanted to know documentation says master at spark://IP:PORT  but when i do so it gives me error. port i use 7077 default and IP as localhost

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is using Spark in Standalone mode.  If your installation of Spark is setting up Standalone cluster then the ip would be the ip of the master node and likely the default port. Otherwise it would need to be whatever matches the cluster setup.  List of clusters supported at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#cluster-manager-types

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherB... One more question as you have mentioned to set the executors for memory and cores. Could you please suggest me as how to find these values with amazon different instance types.  [link]   http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ .

Comment: To answer question in comment I added more to original answer.

Comment: @ChristopherB Great answer thanks! A novice followup question. What do I specify as master if I want to connect remotely using Java code.

Comment: Great answer, do you know how to do it from a sagemaker notebook(using yarn-client instead of going through livy)